# Badge Notification Buggy?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

The notification for when badges are awarded seems to be a bit buggy compared to other sites. It sometimes alerts me and other times it does not. I am not sure if this is intentional or just a simple bug. It really is very minor but I have noticed it so I report. =>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We intentionally hide some of the bronze badge notifications if you have over 200 reputation on another site.

For more details, you can visit https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/96955

For anything further, we'd need to know more specifics (which badges) about what you feel is missing.